# remote: Invalid username or password

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, vim

I am trying to set up vim to develop with Python and I am following [this tutorial](http://www.sontek.net/blog/2011/05/07/turning_vim_into_a_modern_python_ide.html). I'm a total newb with Linux and vim and I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I screenshot my terminal below. I copy and pasted several commands into the terminal at once, just following the tutorial properly, which is pretty brief. The first several commands seem to have worked, but when it asks me my GitHub username and password, it fails. It accepts my GitHub username but it does not take my GitHub password. I know it's the right password because I even changed it on GitHub to make sure I had the right one and it's still failing. I looked at a couple other SO posts on this topic but did not help me to solve my issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: my terminal]

Comment: from the screen i can see you password should work. the `fatal` error is about not being able to clone `minibufexpl.vim.git` and it is not there https://github.com/sontek?tab=repositories

Answer (score 1):

That Git Repo is no longer on github i suggest you use this one below

```
git submodule add https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim.git bundle/minibufexpl
```

or do a google search for another minibufexpl plugin for vim